# If username is invalid, hide links

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is my first time doing much with anything but perl and vb so please bear with me.

I am able to compare two fields which need to match, and if they don't, then I need to hide HTML links completely. How would this be written?

This grabs the first userid

```
($("#trid").val());            
    ($("#pxuserid").text());
    var test = $("#pxuserid").text().indexOf("-");
    var username = $("#pxuserid").text().substring(test + 1);
    (username);
```

This grabs the second userid and changes it from all uppercase to lowercase.

```
($("[name=vsvadm]").val()); 
    var str = $("[name=vsvadm]").text("checked", true).val().toLowerCase();
    (str);
```

These are what I need to show/hide

```
<div class="pxcontent" id="sarea">

   <div class="pxvtab" id="pxform">

      <div class="pxvtablinks">  



       <a href="javascript:act();" rel="#page2">Directories</a>
       <a href="javascript:act();" rel="#page5">Accounting</a>
       <a href="javascript:act();" rel="#page6">Advanced</a>
       <a href="javascript:act();" rel="#page7">Security</a>
```

I'm trying to get the script to say "If userid1 does not equal userid2, then hide Page 5, 6, and 7, but show only page 2, otherwise keep going" 
Hopefully I didn't confuse anyone and someone could help out!

Comment: This should be done server-side, on the client the user can see what's happening (however obfuscated it might be), and you seem to be checking against a value that's held in the site, which your user can access.

Comment: Also FYI, the following of your statements don't do anything, i.e. they retrieve a value and discard it: `($("#trid").val());`, `($("#pxuserid").text());`, `(username);`, `($("[name=vsvadm]").val());`, `(str);`

Answer (score 1):

Give all the `<a>` tags a class:

```
<a href="javascript:act();" class="nav-links" rel="#page2">Directories</a>
<a href="javascript:act();" class="nav-links" rel="#page5">Accounting</a>
<a href="javascript:act();" class="nav-links" rel="#page6">Advanced</a>
<a href="javascript:act();" class="nav-links" rel="#page7">Security</a>
```

And then check for the condition and hide it:

```
if (userid1 != userid2)
  $(".nav-links").hide();
```

> **Note:** This should be really handled on the server side than the client side. Experienced users (and almost everyone now) can access the hidden elements by using the Dev Tools.

Comment: Is there an easy command that will add classes to page 5, 6, 7 only?

Comment: @CharlesZ I guess it is better to handle this using the server side. But yeah.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `str` and `username` are what you want to compare..

```
 if(str !== username) $("a").hide();
```

This hides ALL links, as your question stated, but should not be used to prevent users from viewing them. If your links need to be secure then auth should be done on server side.

Also you can get rid of all the free-standing statements that you wrapped in perens. Those don't serve any purpose.

Answer (score -1):

You need to compare the strings and then loop over the links

```
var username1 = 'username1'
var username2 = 'username2'

// Do compare
if (username1 !== username2) {
    // Loop over the links
    $.each($('.pxvtablinks a'), function() {
        // If it doesn't have a rel attribute equal to '#page2'...
        if ($(this).attr('rel') !== '#page2') {
            // hide it.
            $(this).hide()
        }
    })
}
```

Example: https://codepen.io/mark_c/pen/mAQwpE